# How to save image in upload folder via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written jquery function to upload image as below lines of code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     function previewFile() {
         var preview = document.querySelector('img'); //selects the query named img
         var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0]; //sames as here
         var reader = new FileReader();

         reader.onloadend = function () {
             preview.src = reader.result;
         }

         if (file) {
             reader.readAsDataURL(file); //reads the data as a URL
         } else {
             preview.src = "";
         }
     }
```

Now I want to save the uploaded images in upload folder and then show the image  in img tag from upload folder path. Please help me!!!

Comment: i am using ASP.NET C# and ms sql server but my above requirement has to do nothing with backend.

Comment: You want to **upload** something to your server i. e. your backend.

Comment: Actually i am using jquery plugin where we have to upload image by the help of jquery'

Comment: is it possible to do or not...

Comment: What is your actual question? Where do your uploads go?

Answer (score 0):

Here Code:

Client side:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#fupldId").on("change", function () {
                debugger;
                var t = $("#fupldId")[0].files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(t);
                reader.onloadend = function () {
                  //  alert(reader.result)
                    $.post("http://localhost:49513/File.ashx", reader.result, function () {  preview.src = reader.result; })

                }
               // alert(result);
                debugger;
            });
        });
```

Using ashx control for uploading file and code under ProcessRequest method

```
  // context.Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            int y = context.Request.ContentLength;

            //read image content from request 
            StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream);
            string Base64contentWithContentType = stream.ReadToEnd();


            var ty = Base64contentWithContentType.Split(new string[]{"base64,"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var Base64content = ty[1];
            var contenttype = ty[0];

            var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Base64content);

            //save image
            using (var imageFile = new FileStream("D:/a.jpg", FileMode.Create))
            {
                imageFile.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                imageFile.Flush();
```